# What are the rules for pluralising abbreviations?

Tags: abbreviations, academia

Especially in academic writing, pluralisation of abbreviations is a very handy device: ‘p’→‘pp’¹ is ‘page’→‘pages’, ‘ed’→‘edd’ becomes ‘editors’, ‘ll’ is ‘lines’, ‘nn’ is ‘notes’.² The rule (given ‘ed’→‘edd’) appears to be that the final letter of the abbreviation is doubled in order to pluralise it, but is this correct? So, as the question states: **What are the rules for pluralising abbreviations?** From this follows two sub-question: Are there any notable differences between academic writing and writing for a general audience (except perhaps avoiding too many such abbreviations)? And when using established Latin phrases in English writing, are there any special rules to consider for pluralisation of Latin abbreviations in English texts?

With reference to note 2 below, I am conscious that these abbreviations might have been inherited from mediaeval scribal practice. Could the answer perhaps be found there?³

───

1.   Or ‘pp.’, henceforth without the full stop.

2.   Or ‘pāginæ’, ‘ēditorēs’, ‘līneæ’, ‘notæ’.

3.   Could perhaps ‘qq.v.’ be a legitimate variant of ‘q.v.’, ɔ: for ‘quibus vidē’ rather than ‘quō vidē’? An example (if correct) could be ‘These issues have been discussed earlier, *qq.v. nn.* 13, 27 and 29.’

───

**Comment 1**

I considered adding the `latin` tag, but chose not to, as this question isn’t about Latin specifically, but rather what is customary in English. Should you consider that the `latin` tag indeed belongs to this question, do please say so in the comments, and I will edit it.

**Comment 2**

As pointed out in the comments, we are here dealing with abbreviations renegated to footnotes. I still believe the question holds relevance, though, but it is worth keeping in mind.

Comment: I think you need to clarify one point in your question.  The particular abbreviations are features of bibliographies, footnotes and suchlike:  they are not normally found in formal discursive text.  There are some that can appear within formal text, but then only in brackets:  'sc.' for 'scilicet' is one example; 'vid. sup.' is another.  But these are not nouns and so do not give rise to your problem.

Comment: I understand your question (I think). Should I add the very thing that you write as a comment, perhaps?

Comment: What I should say is that, like all other such features, it is a matter of convention rather than rule.  As long as it is clear that what such abbreviated plurals are, you either follow the style guide of you company/publisher, or what seems to be common practice, or, as in the case of 'editors', do what is likely to me understood.  I looked up the plural of 'ed' and found that 'eds' is already bagged by 'editions'.  Sorry.

Comment: But wouldn’t such style guides base their guides on a general set of rules for English writing?

Comment: I am trying to avoid the word 'rule' of any language, with one exception of one: Esperanto, a language that was actually made up.  Natural languages are not made up:  they evolve in use.  Teachers of languages and of anglophone children as well as the text books they use organise the teaching in classifications and 'rules'.  There is probably no other way.  But the way we learn our own languages is by total immersion.  The 'rules' we appeal to are at best provisional, and the explosion of public and quasi-public communication has accelerated the evolutionary forces.

Comment: So a style guide creates internal consistency.  In general there tend to be a few patterns that are more common than others.  The guide will opt for one of these and editors will then follow this as a genuine 'rule'.  So the rules of grammar are really 'rules of thumb'.  Arguably, this tension between educational and editorial rules of thumb on one hand and natural evolution (and evolution does involve the making of making copying  'mistakes') is the best we can do.  It is to avoid chaos that ELU tries to appeal, where possible, to actual usage.

Comment: While *pp.* is very common and almost universally understood, *edd.* isn't; *eds.* is much more common.

Comment: Related: [Revisiting “ee.g.” (versus “e.g.”)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/563117).